# RC6 - What does 'Unexpected token <' mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am upgrading to RC.6 and I get a lot of errors related to third-party components.  The error will say: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

I have gotten it for ng2-bootstrap, ng2-select, angular2-jwt.  I am pretty sure all of these components do not have a extra < in them.

I had been commenting out the third-party components in an attempt to get past the errors.  Now I am stuck on angular2-jwt - I can't comment this out and have anything meaningful.

Can anyone explain what this means?  Where is this unexpected token?

Comment: that typically means you tried to execute html as if it were javascript, which is a symptom of having an incorrect url path to a resource.

Comment: Are you using anything to build your project (Browserify or something like that). I see that regularly if it's still in the middle bundling the JS file and I hit the URL too soon

Answer (score 0):

> What does 'Unexpected token <' mean?

It means the syntax is not valid JavaScript / TypeScript. e.g.

```
let it<ted;
```

Will yield

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

[image]

## Fix

The error should come with either a stack trace or an error location. *that is what you should use* to figure out where this invalid JS is coming from (most likely html is getting loaded as js).

Comment: I understand what it normally means.  I was asking what this means in this context.  I have valid JS/TS that has been working.  I am upgrading to RC6 and I get this on a lot of third party components with not detailed stack trace.